# Twitter Bootstrap modal issues

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Following is my code to launch a modal using twitter bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Twitter Bootstrap Modals Example</title> 
<meta name="description" content="Creating Modal Window with Twitter Bootstrap">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
<div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
          <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
          <p>You can add some text here.</p>                
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div>
      </div>
<p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo        modal</a></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<!--<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>-->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what's going wrong but the modal is never launched. All that happens is that the "#modalname" is appended to the url in the address bar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You sure `bootstrap-modal.js` (and the other assets) exists? Other than that I don't see any issue with this code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @salman, I don't see a problem either. Here's a jsFiddle with your HTML, the only difference is that I'm loading the javascript and CSS files from a CDN
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/fp4vu/

Triple check that the Bootstrap and CSS files are indeed being loaded on your page. If this still doesn't solve the problem, try loading them from a CDN

This is the HTML I've used

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
<div id="example" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
      <h3>This is a Modal Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
      <p>You can add some text here.</p>                
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
<p><a data-toggle="modal" href="#example" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch demo            modal</a></p>
```

and I'm importing javascript and css from:

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
and

http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

CHeck if any other css property might be ovveriding your bootstrap classes.